# Using GetValue method in instance method of a class in C#

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I have simple class with method `ToHtmlString()` and I want to enumerate all private and instance properties of this object(reference). Why I can't take the value. I see I need to pass object to `GetValue` method in order runtime to know which value of which reference reflection will get, but it seems like I CAN'T do it like that? How can I use `GetValue` while enumerating all properties of this instance?

```
    public string ToHtmlString()
    {
        var source = this;
        var html = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (var property in this.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance))
        {
            html.AppendLine(
                new GenericItemView(
                    (property.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(DescriptionAttribute)) as DescriptionAttribute)?.Description,
                    property.GetValue(source).ToString());
        }

        return html.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Please edit the question with a [mcve] at the same time. Questions are *much* better when we can easily reproduce the problem. Also, state the problem - "Why I can't take the value" doesn't tell us anything about what goes wrong with the code you've presented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are missing a closing ")" and a .ToString()

html.AppendLine(new GenericItemView(                        (property.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(DescriptionAttribute)) as DescriptionAttribute)?.Description,                        property.GetValue(source).ToString()).ToString());

Comment: Yes , more likely I forgot to convert `GenericItemView` object to string. Silly me.